# Scroll bar on row 5 onwards in a html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok i am very confused on how my table can have a scroll bar inside where i wan this row
[image]

onward to have a scroll bar instead of a normal scroll bar outside but so far i dont have any luck is there any way i can do it ?

[image]

As the table list went out of bound due to the massive row
is there a way where after row 5 it cut to either 2nd page of navigation or a infinite scroll bar ?

here the code for the table html

```
<div class="col-md-10">    
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="customer-list" class="table">
            <!-- Loading Spinner Div -->
            <div id="loading-container">
                <p>Fetching all customer data...</p>
                <div id="loading-spinner"></div>
            </div>
            <tbody>
                                            
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I have try using datatable plugin but some how it dont work also

Answer (score 0):

I think by your question I understood that you want to freeze few rows. You can freeze few rows by putting them into a different `tbody` and assign `position: sticky` along with `top:0`.

See the html and css for `.freeze-me` class in Snippet below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
tbody{
  width: 100%;
  }
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
}
table, tbody, tr, th, td{
  background: white;
}

tbody.freeze-me{
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody class="freeze-me">
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Freeze</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>till</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>here</td><td>-</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>13</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>14</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>15</td><td>scrollable</td><td>-</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/3sjL4okh/19/) also.